# Setting value for label using ComponentQuery.query()

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have created a Window, and added a label. Now i want to access that label using `query` and set text to that label. How am i suppose to do it ? I need to change the Text of the label (`firstlabel`) using 
`Ext.ComponentQuery.query`. Can someone help me please ?

```
Ext.define('ProjectExample.view.ex.FirstWin', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.firstW',
    items: [
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'First Panel',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                name: 'firstlabel',
                text: 'THIS IS A LABEL'
                }]
    ];  
    var panelArr = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
var label = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('window > panel > label')[0];
label.setText('new label text');
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/XuQg4/